# Angular login function in service with HTTPClient

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, response

since i've upgraded to Angular 5 and started using httpclient. I am unable to get just a simple login function to work. Can someone help me out?

auth service:

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.post(environment.api_url + '/authenticate', {email: email, password: password})
      .map(response => {
          if (response && response.token) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
      )
      .catch(err => Observable.of(false));
  }
```

and the login page controller:

```
login() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.auth.login(this.credentials.email, this.credentials.password)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          if (data) {
            this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
          }
        },
        data => {
          this.loading = false;
          if (data.error && data.error.message) {
            this.loginError = data.error.message;
          }
        });
  }
```

This gives me error(s):

> ERROR in src/app/services/auth.service.ts(104,36): error TS2339: Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Object'. src/app/services/auth.service.ts(105,52): error TS2339: Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Answer (score 1):

With `http`, the response body was typed as `any`, which meant you could use whatever properties you needed without TypeScript complaining. This changed with `HttpClient`, whereby it defaults to just a standard `Object`, which upsets TypeScript as a basic object does not have a `token` property.

You have at least 3 basic options here:

1. Change from `response.token` to `response['token']`.
2. Use `this.http.post<any>` and continue to access `response.token`.
3. Create e.g. a new interface, such as the following:

   ```
   interface AuthenticateResponse {
       token: string
   }
   ```

   With this, you can then use `this.http.post<AuthenticateResponse>` and have the type-safety offered by TypeScript.

You can read more about this in [Typechecking the response](https://angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response) from the docs.